# How to get 'feed' method in User model not private so I can show feeds in my static_page/home page (Michael Hartl Rails Tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, models

I'm following the Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#code-home_with_feed) and I'm in chapter 10.36 where we are creating feeds of microposts to be shown on the Home page of the user. When I get to section 10.41 I should be able to see all of the posts on the home page but I keep getting an

```
NoMethodError in StaticPagesController#home
private method `feed' called for #<User:0x007f881cf77410>

if signed_in?
        @micropost = current_user.microposts.build if signed_in?
        @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page]) <-- error line
    end 
 end
```

How do I get User.feed method to not be private so I can use in in the home page?

The code for user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :create_remember_token
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence:   true,
                      format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end

def feed
    # This is preliminary. See "Following users" for the full implementation.
    Micropost.where("user_id = ?", id)
end

def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end
```

The code for the static_page controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if signed_in?
        @micropost = current_user.microposts.build if signed_in?
        @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end

end
```

The code for the home page view

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
      <section>
        <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
      </section>
      <section>
        <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
      </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="span8">
      <h3>Post Feed</h3>
      <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

'shared/feed' file

```
<% if @feed_item.any %>
    <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
    </ol>
    <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error `private method`feed' called for #`,

You are calling a `private` method named `feed` on an instance of `User`model.

In order to get the below code working

```
 @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

**Make sure that method `feed` in `User` model is not under `private` section.**

Just remember, a private method (i.e. a method declared outside of any class) can't be called on other objects.

**UPDATE**

You closed the `User` class before the defined methods. Hence, the error.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ## ...
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end  ## REMOVE THIS end

def feed
   ## ...

private

def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
end

end ## ADD THIS end
```

Comment: Hi Kirti, thanks for you reply. I just edited in my user.rb file. I don't have the feed method under the private section within user.rb but I still the get the error.

Comment: See the `UPDATE` section in my answer.

Comment: @djsjc Glad to help. :) Please accept the answer by checking the checkmark next to my answer. If you don't know how to do it, read here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235